# c# declaring variables inside or outside a constructor

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand the difference in variable declaration of a class inside or outside of a constructor. In this case creating the list for grades. To me, the below achieves the same result so which would be recommended and is there any reason why I should do one or the other? I have one way commented out and the other not.

```
class Book
{
    //List<double> grades;
    List<double> grades = new List<double>();
    public Book()
    {
        //Why not declare it here?
        //grades = new List<double>();
    }

    public void AddGrade(double grade)
    {
        grades.Add(grade);
    }
}
```

Comment: The List is an instance variable. If you declare it in the constructor, it's a local variable which goes out of scope once the constructor exits.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Um no, that's not true at all.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill: Looking at the commented-out lines, I think OP means why not split the declaration from the initialization.

Comment: This comes down to preference as it's quite opinion based. I like to do it in the constructor so I can see **when and what** gets instanciated/set. But again, there a other reasons for not doing it there e.g. less code in the constructor. If the fields aren't readonly you can also use another method to set them. I'm voting to close as primarly opinion based.

Comment: Usually in constructor one initializes properties which depend on constructor parameters or require complicated computations. In this case I would go with out-of-constructor initialization, but I believe either way is considered OK.

Comment: The two methods you describe here are identical in terms of functionality. In practice, it's likely more important to be consistent rather than worry about anything else.

Comment: @DavidG He's not declaring it; he's initializing it.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Yes, and your comment is flat out wrong.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yes.

Comment: The biggest difference is when there are multiple constructors. Initializing a class member in one place can be nice.

Comment: @DavidG The OP's code asked 'Why not declare it here?' I answered that.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Yes, and there is no declaration in the constructor, there is only initialisation so nothing is going out of scope.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey multiple constructors and they are not chained. i.e. they all call `base(...)` with various overloads and there is no way to chain them.

Comment: @DavidG My last word: again, the OP asked 'Why not declare it here?'

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill And look at the code, not the incorrect terminology used, OP is talking about initialisation, not declaration.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill: It's generally better to read between the lines and answer the _intended_ question rather than giving a technically-correct answer that misses the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a fair bit of room for personal opinion here, but in general terms:

1. Declaring and initializing the field on the same line helps you to verify the field is initialized without needing to look in multiple places. If you see a field declared without an initializer, you have to look in a different part of code to see whether the item is being initialized at all.
2. There are circumstances (like when the initial value is based on a constructor argument) when you cannot initialize the field inline. Since you will *sometimes* need to initialize fields in the constructor, some people will argue that it's more consistent to *always* initialize them there.

You may also want to ask: Should I be requiring/allowing an initial value to be provided in the constructor?

```
    class Book
    {
        readonly List<double> grades;
        public Book() : this(Array.Empty<double>())
        {
        }

        public Book(IEnumerable<double> grades)
        {
            this.grades = grades.ToList();
        }

        public void AddGrade(double grade)
        {
            grades.Add(grade);
        }
    }
```

And: should my class actually just be a dumb data container without a constructor or logic? (Is `book.AddGrade(...)` really more sensible than `book.Grades.Add(...)`?)

```
    class Book
    {
        public List<double> Grades {get;} = new List<double>();
    }
```

Comment: The field will be initialized to the default value for the type if one is not specified.

Comment: One other thing to note is the order of the initialization.  If I remember correctly, fields that are initialized in line (i.e., outside of the constructor) get initialized as if the code was prefixed to the constructor that is being run.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill: Yes, technically that's true. I generally think of a `null`-initialized field as being effectively uninitialized.

Comment: Yes, it's not very useful.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, you remember correctly.